# What versions (if any) of JBoss are affected by the Heartbleed vulnerability?

Tags: security, ssl, jboss, heartbleed-bug

Anyone know the best way to determine whether my JBoss application is vulnerable to the [heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com/) security bug?

I am using JBoss versions 4.0.4 and 5.1.0.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software versions, administration and patching. Server Fault has quite a few questions on the topic: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed.

Answer (score 4):

A good [explanation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55139/does-the-heartbleed-vulnerability-affect-apache-tomcat-servers-using-tomcat-nati) is on the security StackExchange site. The answer linked is specific to Tomcat, but applicable to JBoss (or other Java applications) as well. The short answer is no, because Java implements its own stack of SSL/TLS and does not relay on the OpenSSL or any other SSL implementation library.

> Tomcat is written in Java, and Java has its own allocation system (the
>   famous garbage collector) which obtains memory from the OS by huge
>   blocks, quite apart from the zones where OpenSSL obtains its blocks.
>
> Thus, the heartbleed buffer overrun is unlikely to reveal any secret
>   information which exists as Java-based object. It may, however, obtain
>   information which is allocated from the same heap as where OpenSSL
>   obtains its own buffers. In particular, it is possible that the
>   vulnerability may reveal part or all of the private key used by
>   OpenSSL itself.

Comment: Tomcat are written in Java but are the Java classpath SSL implementation written in Java?